# I try to write a cycle instead of recursive function

Tags: c++, algorithm

I try to find clusters in array. For example, I have such array:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 3 0 1
0 8 5 0 7
7 0 0 0 4
```

After I launched the program, it will print such rezults:

```
Cluster 1: <2,3,8,5,7>

Cluster 2: <1,7,4>
```

I've made recursive function to resolve this problem:

```
void DFS(int x, int y)
{
  printf("%d ", g[x][y]);
  g[x][y] = 0;
  // iterate over neighbours
  for(dx=-1; dx<=1; dx++)
    for(dy=-1; dy<=1; dy++)
      if (g[x+dx][y+dy]) DFS(x+dx, y+dy);
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    if (g[i][j])
    {
      DFS(i, j);
      printf("\n");
    }
```

But there is the problem: I need to process extra large arrays, so when recursive function calls itself more than ~1000 times, the program finished with an error "Stack overflow".

So I need to remake this code without usage of recursive functions. 
I tried to use lists, cicles and so on, but it doesn't work properly.

Can you tell me, how can I do this?

TRY TO EXPLAIN AGAIN:

```
// random_number_gererator.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//Задаем максимально возможный размер стека
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:100000000000")

using namespace std;

const int k = 2;                                        //размерность массива
const int N = k * k * k;                                //количество элементов, которые необходимо сгенерировать
int number0 = 0, number1 = 0;

int generation(float probability);                      //прототип функции генерации псевдослучайных чисел
int create_array();                                     //прототип функции создания трехмерного массива

int ***ptrarray = new int **[k];                        //указатель на трехмерный массив

ofstream fout("clusters.txt");

int find_and_write_clusters(int X, int Y, int Z);       //прототип функции поиска кластеров

int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");                           //установка русской кодировки
    int err = create_array();                           //вызов функции создания трехмерного массива
                                                        //cout << err<<endl;
    generation(0.3);                                    //функция генерации и заполнения массива
                                                        //После генерации данные заполнились в массив ptrarray[][][]

    for (int X = 0; X < k; X++) {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < k; Y++) {
            for (int Z = 0; Z < k; Z++) {
                if (ptrarray[X][Y][Z] == 1) {
                    find_and_write_clusters(X, Y, Z);   //вызываем рекурсивную функцию поиска и записи кластеров
                    fout << endl;
                    fout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fout.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int generation(float probability) {
    int prob_persent = ceil(probability * 10000);       //введенная пользователем вероятность, в процентах до 10 000 (для большей точности)
    int T;
    if (probability > 1 || probability < 0) return 1;

    for (int X = 0; X < k; X++) {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < k; Y++) {
            for (int Z = 0; Z < k; Z++) {
                T = 0 + rand() % 10001;
                if (T <= prob_persent) {
                    ptrarray[X][Y][Z] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    ptrarray[X][Y][Z] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int X = 0; X < k; X++) {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < k; Y++) {
            for (int Z = 0; Z < k; Z++) {
                cout << ptrarray[X][Y][Z];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
int create_array() {
    for (int X = 0; X < k; X++) {
        ptrarray[X] = new int *[k];
        for (int Y = 0; Y < k; Y++) {
            ptrarray[X][Y] = new int[k];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int find_and_write_clusters(int X, int Y, int Z) {
    if (ptrarray[X][Y][Z] == 1) {
        //Здесь проверить, есть ли такой элемент в файле
        fout << X << ";" << Y << ";" << Z << " ";
        //Заменяем текущий элемент на 0, чтобы он больше не обрабатывался
        ptrarray[X][Y][Z] = 0;
        if (X + 1 < k) find_and_write_clusters(X + 1, Y, Z);
        if (Y + 1 < k) find_and_write_clusters(X, Y + 1, Z);
        if (Z + 1 < k) find_and_write_clusters(X, Y, Z + 1);

        if (X - 1 >= 0) find_and_write_clusters(X - 1, Y, Z);
        if (Y - 1 >= 0) find_and_write_clusters(X, Y - 1, Z);
        if (Z - 1 >= 0) find_and_write_clusters(X, Y, Z - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is full code. In this one, our program generates 3D-array and fill it with "0" and "1" numbers. 
After that, program find clustert with usage such algorithm (for example, we made 2*2*2 array:

```
10
01

11
00
```

Here we have 2 layers, 8 elements (2*2*2) in total.

How to find clusters:
We scan our array and call the function find_and_write_clusters. If element equal to "1", we call this function in neighbour elements. And so on.

Now, if yoy compile and run this code, you will get file "clusters.txt" with 2 rows. I'll try to paint it for you

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a `main()` function and the `#include` statements, and then shrink your code to the smallest program possible that produces your problem. We call this a [mcve]. This allows members to copy, paste, compile, and then Help you.

Comment: Please expand on "it doesn't work properly". What is the problem, exactly? And where is the non-working code?

Comment: @user463035818 The OP "tried to use lists, cicles _[sic]_ and so on" and there is some "it" that "doesn't work properly", so yes it exists.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh missed that.

Comment: Please show the code that you need help with, not the code that you want to get rid of. Often the border between asking to write the code and asking to help with broken code is thin. Just show us your attempt and it can be fixed, while just asking for the solution is unlikely to make someone write a full code for you

Comment: How do you define a cluster? What are the conditions that need to be met in order to return a cluster from a 2D array of numbers?

Comment: From what i understand your definition of cluster is any horizontally, vertically or diagonally adjacient non-zero value, is that correct?

Comment: It is impossible to help you without guessing what a cluster means. That said, recursion is wasteful and will get you in trouble. Why not process the matrix left to right to to bottom and incrementally build your clusters as you go.

Comment: And what about "edge effects" where x = 0 , x = DIM_X, y = 0, y = DIM_Y?? You may end up reaching "outside" the array.

Comment: @Olumide the "edge effects" were taken into consideration.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos I work with 3D arrays, but I wrote about 2D array, just to explain all of you how it works. Let me explain again. Now, I'm going to add full code and write more details.

Comment: @ЯригаОлег: That's fine. You can add more code to further explain the situation in 2D. If you want to, just try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Barnack It was a simple explanation for you to understand. In total, it is correct, that you say, but I use 3D array and do not touch "diagonally" elements. Just non-zero elements that are located in the front, back, top, bottom, left and right from the "parent" element.

Comment: @ЯригаОлег: The way I solved this problem, without using recursion, is by following an agent-remainder approach. It's similar-ish to an A* algorithm. The idea is simple. Imagine all the zeroes are the sea, and the numbers close to each other form small islands. You go through your array until you find a non-zero number which becomes your agent. The agent searches the surrounding numbers and appends them to a an array of clusters. Each visited element becomes zero, thus preventing the agent from revisiting that element. While the array has zeroes, keep searching for more clusters, else, quit.

Comment: @ЯригаОлег: I'm not sure how efficient this approach is - that's why I haven't posted it as an answer. But in 3D you can implement a similar approach and then use a spacial hash or oct-trees to speed up your computations, depending on whether or not your elements move. Let me know if this is something of interest and I can share the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your description `So I need to remake this code without usage of recursive functions. I tried to use lists, cicles and so on, but it doesn't work properly.` is very vague.

It would be a lot better if you just started the question by having a reduced example (i.e just a fixed array, the random generation really wasn't relevant to the question) of the recursive code and then also included your `doesn't work properly` try. Then it would be easier for us to help you learn.

Anyway here's a version of the function that's a straight translation of the recursive version to something that stores the data on the heap. You can use another data structure if `vector` doesn't suite your use-case but I think it might be serviceable until really large.

```
int find_and_write_clusters(int X, int Y, int Z) {
    struct IState {
        int X, Y, Z, step;
    };
    std::vector<IState> remaining;
    auto insertIfOne = [&remaining](int X, int Y, int Z) {
        if (ptrarray[X][Y][Z] == 1) {
            fout << X << ";" << Y << ";" << Z << " ";
            ptrarray[X][Y][Z] = 0;
            remaining.emplace_back(IState{ X, Y, Z, 0 });
        }
    };
    insertIfOne(X, Y, Z);
    while (!remaining.empty())
    {
        auto& c = remaining.back();//current
        switch (c.step++)
        {
        case 0:
            if (c.X + 1 < k) insertIfOne(c.X + 1, c.Y, c.Z);
            break;
        case 1:
            if (c.Y + 1 < k) insertIfOne(c.X, c.Y + 1, c.Z);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (c.Z + 1 < k) insertIfOne(c.X, c.Y, c.Z + 1);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (c.X - 1 >= 0) insertIfOne(c.X - 1, c.Y, c.Z);
            break;
        case 4:
            if (c.Y - 1 >= 0) insertIfOne(c.X, c.Y - 1, c.Z);
            break;
        case 5:
            if (c.Z - 1 >= 0) insertIfOne(c.X, c.Y, c.Z - 1);
            break;
        default:
            remaining.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But your approach is very inefficient to start with. You can save a lot of complexity by using a [`Two-pass approach`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Two-pass) (although I guess for 3D you'd need to merge connected 2d labels across layers, still cheaper than all the branching and cache missing you're doing now) instead of iterating over the data irregularly for each label like you're doing now.

**edit:** if the lambda is confusing, the code is equivalent to this version without the lambda

```
struct IState {
    int X, Y, Z, step;
};

void insertIfOne(std::vector<IState>& stack, int X, int Y, int Z)
{
    if (ptrarray[X][Y][Z] == 1) {
        fout << X << ";" << Y << ";" << Z << " ";
        ptrarray[X][Y][Z] = 0;
        stack.emplace_back(IState{ X, Y, Z, 0 });
    }
}

int find_and_write_clusters(int X, int Y, int Z) {
    std::vector<IState> remaining;
    insertIfOne(remaining, X, Y, Z);
    while (!remaining.empty())
    {
        auto& c = remaining.back();//current
        switch (c.step++)
        {
        case 0:
            if (c.X + 1 < k) insertIfOne(remaining, c.X + 1, c.Y, c.Z);
            break;
        case 1:
            if (c.Y + 1 < k) insertIfOne(remaining, c.X, c.Y + 1, c.Z);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (c.Z + 1 < k) insertIfOne(remaining, c.X, c.Y, c.Z + 1);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (c.X - 1 >= 0) insertIfOne(remaining, c.X - 1, c.Y, c.Z);
            break;
        case 4:
            if (c.Y - 1 >= 0) insertIfOne(remaining, c.X, c.Y - 1, c.Z);
            break;
        case 5:
            if (c.Z - 1 >= 0) insertIfOne(remaining, c.X, c.Y, c.Z - 1);
            break;
        default:
            remaining.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks! It seems like this works properly. Oh, I see my mistake - I tried to define the list (or vector) as the global var, but it should be local, as I can see.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain what this code does? 
```
auto insertIfOne = [&remaining](int X, int Y, int Z) {
  if (ptrarray[X][Y][Z] == 1) {
   fout << X << ";" << Y << ";" << Z << " ";
   ptrarray[X][Y][Z] = 0;
   remaining.emplace_back(IState{ X, Y, Z, 0 });
  }
 };
```

Comment: it's just a lambda, to save on copy-pasting code. Just used here as a kind of typesafe macro. It does the `if` you have at the beginning of your function and adds the next "recursive call" to the list only when it would pass the if. You can do it without the lambda

Comment: @ЯригаОлег I added a version without the lambda for clarity.

Comment: Oh. thank you! It seems like I need to read more theoretical material about lambda. Your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score -7):

Every recursive construction can be replaced with a stack construction and vice versa. Try replacing your recursive logic with a stack datatype.

This is C#, but this concept applies to all languages: https://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/04/Replacing_Recursion_With_a_Stack.aspx/

Comment: True but not a very helpful answer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit asking op what he means when its clear what the problem is isn't helpful either.

Comment: You are overreacting and twisting facts. The op clearly stated that he got a stackoverflow exception. " the only description of the problem was "it doesn't work"?" is nonsense. -> "I don't need lecturing by you on how to help people on this website thank you!" -> sure but I don't need your emotional garbage either.

Comment: No, the stack overflow was the problem with the recursive approach. OP then correctly attempted a loop-based approach but did not adequately describe the problem with said approach. We're done here!